# Android Webview Performance improvement by caching

Tags: android, performance, listview, webview

I am working on and Android app which has legacy code and we are using ListView and optimizing the listview by using ViewHolder.

Our listview has different types of custom views which are a bit complext. The scrolling performance of the listview is pretty good till now.
A new requirement has come up to support Webviews in the same listview. The webview content to be loaded from disk and javascript is enabled.

The problem is that when I add webviews in list the scrolling become jittery. During the scrolling I can see that the webview content is blank as it is still to be loaded.

I think the performance degradation is due to two reasons.
1) creation+Loading of new Webviews everytime getView of listview adapter is called
2) Displaying the content of webview

To solve these issues I started caching 7 webviews and I am recycling the webviews by detaching from previous parent view and attaching to new parent view. For example if the current visible item index is 5. I will also create the webview for three next(6,7,8) and three prev(2,3,4) items and keep them in a cache based on some id of listview item content. So when there is requirement for next item say for index 6, I will simply return one item from cache and update the both from front and back to hold 3,4,5 and 7,8,9 index items.

I was thinking that by creating a pool of webviews I will solve both the problems. 1) creating new webview ever time getview is called. And by prefetching the next/prev 3-3 items I can preload url so display will happen in background.

But I can see that display is still taking time and scrolling is still jittery.

So my questions are:- 
Does webview display the content only when it is attach to a window ? (In my case the webviews in caches are not attached to window and I am loading the url in them.)
Does webview display the content only when it is visible ?
Is there a way to render the content of webview in background so that by creating cache of Webview I can do smooth scrolling.

Comment: May I suggest using Chrome custom tabs.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.I need to load the Local HTML pages so Webview is more suited. Also I dont want to show top bar of Chrome Tabs where user can type the Url as the url is provided programmatically.